# Predict using randomForest package in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

How can I use result of `randomForest` call in **R** to predict labels on some unlabled data (e.g. real world input to be classified)?
Code:

```
train_data = read.csv("train.csv")
input_data = read.csv("input.csv")
result_forest = randomForest(Label ~ ., data=train_data)
labeled_input = result_forest.predict(input_data) # I need something like this
```

train.csv:

```
a;b;c;label;
1;1;1;a;
2;2;2;b;
1;2;1;c;
```

input.csv:

```
a;b;c;
1;1;1;
2;1;2;
```

I need to get something like this

```
a;b;c;label;
1;1;1;a;
2;1;2;b;
```

Comment: `predict(result_forest, newdata=input_data)`.

Comment: @eipi10, thanks a lot. Thats my first day of R. You can rewrite your comment as answer to let me accept it

Comment: There are lots of questions on Stack Overflow related to `predict`, so I'd guess this question is probably a duplicate. No need for me to add an answer. The key thing to remember for future reference is that just about every modeling function is R has a `predict` "method", meaning that if you run `predict` on the model object, it will return predictions for the training data by default, or predictions for new data if you use the `newdata` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me know if this is what you are getting at.

You train your randomforest with your training data:

```
# Training dataset
train_data <- read.csv("train.csv")
#Train randomForest
forest_model <- randomForest(label ~ ., data=train_data)
```

Now that the randomforest is trained, you want to give it new data so it can predict what the labels are.

```
input_data$predictedlabel <- predict(forest_model, newdata=input_data)
```

The above code adds a new column to your input_data showing the predicted label.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the predict function

for example:

```
data(iris)
set.seed(111)
ind <- sample(2, nrow(iris), replace = TRUE, prob=c(0.8, 0.2))
iris.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris[ind == 1,])
iris.pred <- predict(iris.rf, iris[ind == 2,])
```

This is from http://ugrad.stat.ubc.ca/R/library/randomForest/html/predict.randomForest.html